# Alphanumeric date to numeric in shell

Tags: shell, awk

I have a data file where dates are alphanumeric at each 10 minutes. e.g.

```
00 hour 00 minute (00:00H)
00 hour 10 minute (00:10H)
00 hour 20 minute (00:20H)
and so on
```

$ ifile.txt

```
00:00H01JUN2021 1.900
00:10H01JUN2021 2.400
00:20H01JUN2021 2.100
00:30H01JUN2021 2.300
00:40H01JUN2021 2.00
00:50H01JUN2021 2.300
01:00H01JUN2021 2.300
01:10H01JUN2021 0.000
01:20H01JUN2021 2.200
01:30H01JUN2021 0.100
```

To understand the data:

1st column is date; second column is the value at that time

First 6 letters YY:XXH indicats as YY -> Hour; XX -> Minute (as explained in the begining)

I would like to convert it into a CSV file with numeric dates. The desire outfile is

$ ofile.txt

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh-mn-sc,val
2021-06-01 00:00:00,1.900
2021-06-01 00:10:00,2.400
2021-06-01 00:20:00,2.100
2021-06-01 00:30:00,2.300
2021-06-01 00:40:00,2.000
2021-06-01 00:50:00,2.300
2021-06-01 01:00:00,2.300
2021-06-01 01:10:00,0.000
2021-06-01 01:20:00,2.200
2021-06-01 01:30:00,0.100
```

My script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
gawk '
    BEGIN {
        month["Jan"] = "01"; month["Feb"] = "02"; month["Mar"] = "03";
        month["Apr"] = "04"; month["May"] = "05"; month["Jun"] = "06";
        month["Jul"] = "07"; month["Aug"] = "08"; month["Sep"] = "09";
        month["Oct"] = "10"; month["Nov"] = "11"; month["Dec"] = "12";
    }
    function timestamp_to_numeric(s) {
        # 00:00H01JUN2021 => 2021-06-01 00:00:00
        return substr(s,12,4)"-"month[substr(s,9,3)]"-"substr(s,7,2) substr(s,1,2)":"substr(s,4,2)":""00"
    }
    NR==1 {next}
    END {
            printf "%s",timestamp_to_numeric($1),$2
            printf "\n"
        }
   ' ifile.txt
```

This script is not priniting my desired output.

Comment: Please, add what fails with your script.

Comment: `month["Jun"] = "06"` etc. can't work without further manipulation since your input uses all upper case month abbreviations like `JUN`. The printfs in your END section also won't work due to more value args than the format allows, plus accessing fields there is undefined behavior (but will probably be OK in gawk), and there's no reason to use 2 printfs there instead of 1 print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
return substr(s,12,4)"-"month[substr(s,9,3)]"-"substr(s,7,2) substr(s,1,2)":"substr(s,4,2)":""00"
```

to

```
return substr(s,12,4)"-"month[substr(s,9,3)]"-"substr(s,7,2)" "substr(s,1,2)":"substr(s,4,2)":""00"
# .................................,........................^^^
```

so that you actually have a space between the date and the time.

Perhaps more readable would be:

```
return sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:00", substr(s,12,4), month[substr(s,9,3)], substr(s,7,2), substr(s,1,2), substr(s,4,2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk (since you're already using it) for the 4th arg to `split()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function timestamp_to_numeric(s,        mthNr,t,m) {
    # 00:00H01JUN2021 => 2021-06-01 00:00:00
    split(s,t,/[[:alpha:]]+/,m)
    mthNr = index("  JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",m[2]) / 3
    return sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %s:00", t[3], mthNr, t[2], t[1])
}

BEGIN {
    OFS=","
    print "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mn-sc","val"
}
{ print timestamp_to_numeric($1), $2 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk ifile.txt
yyyy-mm-dd hh-mn-sc,val
2021-06-01 00:00:00,1.900
2021-06-01 00:10:00,2.400
2021-06-01 00:20:00,2.100
2021-06-01 00:30:00,2.300
2021-06-01 00:40:00,2.00
2021-06-01 00:50:00,2.300
2021-06-01 01:00:00,2.300
2021-06-01 01:10:00,0.000
2021-06-01 01:20:00,2.200
2021-06-01 01:30:00,0.100
```

Answer (score 0):

To put it together in `awk`, without being dependent on `gawk` to get seps from array-splitting (confirmed working on `mawk | gawk | nawk`) :

```
echo "${...input_data...}" | awk '

   function ____(__,_,___) {
        return \
        sprintf((_ = (_ = "%s%.*d")_)(_)_,
                _ = ___, (_+=++_)^_++,
                       substr(__, ___ = length(__)-_--),
                "-",_,
        index("=ANEBARPRAYUNULUGEPCTOVEC", 
                       substr(__, ___-= _,_) ) /_,
                "-",_, substr(__, ___-= _+!!_),
                " ",_,        __, ___ = ":",_, 
                       substr(__,_+_),___,_,!_)
    }
    BEGIN {
         print "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mn-sc" (OFS = ",\t") "val"
    }
    ($++NF = ____($!_))^_'
```

> 

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh-mn-sc,    val
00:00H01JUN2021,    1.900,  2021-06-01 00:00:00
00:10H01JUN2021,    2.400,  2021-06-01 00:10:00
00:20H01JUN2021,    2.100,  2021-06-01 00:20:00
00:30H01JUN2021,    2.300,  2021-06-01 00:30:00
00:40H01JUN2021,    2.00,   2021-06-01 00:40:00
00:50H01JUN2021,    2.300,  2021-06-01 00:50:00
01:00H01JUN2021,    2.300,  2021-06-01 01:00:00
01:10H01JUN2021,    0.000,  2021-06-01 01:10:00
01:20H01JUN2021,    2.200,  2021-06-01 01:20:00
01:30H01JUN2021,    0.100,  2021-06-01 01:30:00
```

===================

To map english month names (*full or abbr.*) of any casing to month #, this *extremely*-odd-looking lookup string suffices —

> - it pre-segregates the input by whether 2nd letter is `A|a` - i.e. `Jan / March / May`
> - then performs reference string position lookup of the 3rd letter

```
function month_name_to_num(__,_) {
    return \
    index(substr("n_r_yb_r_nlgptvc",
    ((_+=++_)-+-++_)^(__!~"^.[Aa]")),
       tolower(substr(__,_--,--_) ) )
}

OCT 10
AUGUST 8
March 3
May 5
October 10
November 11
February 2
JUNE 6
NOV 11
JUL 7
December 12
OCTOBER 10
FEBRUARY 2
JANUARY 1
MARCH 3
APRIL 4
June 6
April 4
September 9
NOVEMBER 11
January 1
FEB 2
MAY 5
DEC 12
MAY 5
JAN 1
JULY 7
SEP 9
August 8
SEPTEMBER 9
July 7
DECEMBER 12
MAR 3
APR 4
JUN 6
AUG 8
```

if you don't want to use `regex`, this function variant bypasses the need to allocate extra temp variable(s) by repurposing the data input one(s) —- something uniquely convenient in weakly-typed languages like `awk` :

```
function monthname2num(_) {
    return \
    index("=anebarprayunulugepctovec",
    tolower(substr(_ "",_+=_^=_,_)))/_
}
```